# Redirect path to another in Tomcat

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, url-rewriting

I add valve into `conf/server.xml` of my tomcat
and I created the file `rewrite.config` in `conf/catalina/localhost`

and I wrote in my file these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect /testapp/?app=global_search#h_global_search /search
```

but nothing happened...

I want to redirect the URL:

```
/testapp/?app=global_search#h_global_search
```

to

```
/search
```

Actually I want all URLs that have this structure:
`/testapp/....#h_global_search` (can be multiple parameters in the query string)

will move to `/search?app=1...&...&...`
with all query string that inserted in the source URL.

Comment: "will move to `/search?app=1...&...&...`" - What's the significance of the `1` at the start of the query string?

Answer (score 0):

> `/testapp/....#h_global_search` (can be multiple parameter in the query string)

Assuming `....` is a query string, not the URL-path?

You can't match the fragment identifier (everything after the `#`) since this is not sent to the server.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app=global_search$
RewrietRule ^testapp/$ /search [R,L]
```

The query string is preserved across the redirect in the above rule. So the above will 302 redirect `/testapp/?app=global_search` to `/search?app=global_search`. For *any* query string (and *no* query string) then remove the `RewriteCond` directive entirely.

To match any query string (but there must be a query string) then change the `RewriteCond` directive to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```